# find out prime no among billions of numbers

Tags: algorithm

i got follwoing question somewhere but not satisfied by my answer.

qtn:
you have given a list of numbers that can be 10 billion numers.
now you have to find out which are prime no among all of them.

I answered , to find a prime no we have to iterate through the loop for billion number 
and check one by one weather its prime or not .
we can put some optimization check here if no is even we wil not check , since prime no can not be even.
and to store the no we can use double array because double is size of 8 byte so it can handle billion number also.
but still it seems he was not satisfied.
please help here what could be more reasonable answer here.
Thanks!

Comment: Is this a Maths question? belongs to http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: what is the rangeof the 10 billion numbers? how large could the numbers be?

Comment: checking if the number is even is not really an optimization, its the first step of the general check of whether the number is prime

Comment: Using a floating point array to store prime numbers is probably not a good idea.

Comment: A fast way to eliminate many of the numbers is the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: look for isprime tests there are tons of them out there ... here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22477240/2521214 is mine

Comment: btw in interviews there is sometimes asking the right questions about your task more important then the answer itself... float/double numbers loose precision so you can not test big numbers properly, .... count of numbers isnot the same as their range btw

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, we are storing the prime numbers in an array. According to [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes):

1. Create a list of consecutive integers from 2 through 10¹⁰: (2, 3, 4, ...., 10¹⁰).
2. Initially, let *p* equal 2, the smallest prime number.
3. Enumerate the multiples of *p* by counting to *10¹⁰* from *2p* in increments of *p*, and mark them in the list (these will be *2p*, *3p*, *4p*, ....; the *p* itself should not be marked).
4. Insert *p* in the array.
5. Find the first number greater than *p* in the list that is not marked. If there was no such number, stop. Otherwise, let *p* now equal to this new number (which is the next prime), and repeat from step 3.

When the algorithm terminates, you will have stored all the prime numbers below 10¹⁰ in the array.

#### Example

To find all the prime numbers less than or equal to 20, the procedure will be:

First generate a list of integers from 2 to 20:

> 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

The first number in the list is 2; cross out every 2nd number in the list after 2 by counting up from 2 in increments of 2 (these will be all the multiples of 2 in the list):

> 2 3 <s>4</s> 5 <s>6</s> 7 <s>8</s> 9 <s>10</s> 11 <s>12</s> 13 <s>14</s> 15 <s>16</s> 17 <s>18</s> 19 <s>20</s>

The next number in the list after 2 is 3; cross out every 3rd number in the list after 3 by counting up from 3 in increments of 3 (these will be all the multiples of 3 in the list):

> 2 3 <s>4</s> 5 <s>6</s> 7 <s>8</s> <s>9</s> <s>10</s> 11 <s>12</s> 13 <s>14</s> <s>15</s> <s>16</s> 17 <s>18</s> 19 <s>20</s>

The next number not yet crossed out in the list after 3 is 5; cross out every 5th number in the list after 5 by counting from 5 in increments of 5 (i.e. all the multiples of 5), but they all have been crossed out at this point as these numbers (10, 15, 20) are also multiples of smaller primes because 5*5 is greater than 20. The numbers not crossed out in the list at this point are all the prime numbers below 20:

> 2 3     5    7           11       13              17      19

To make it more efficient, as you have said, you can initially list odd numbers only, (3, 5, ...., 10⁹), and count in increments of *2p* from *p²* in step 3, thus marking only odd multiples of *p*.

Another way of making it efficient is to, mark the numbers in step 3 starting from *p²*, as all the smaller multiples of *p* will have already been marked at that point. This means that the algorithm is allowed to terminate at step 5 when *p²* is greater than *10¹⁰*.

You can also look up **Segmented Sieve** if you are low on memory and need to generate prime numbers in a smaller range.