# isPrime function (list + % operator)

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, primes

I am trying to get a function to determine if N is a prime number. I am new to Python and I know this may not be the most efficient way to solve this but this is my attempt

```
def is_prime(N):
    k = []                                     #Creates a new list k
    for i in range(2,N):                       #For each i from 2 -> N
        r = N%i                                # r is the remainder of N % i
        k.append(r)                            # appends each remainder r to list k

        if (i == N-1):                         #Once index equals N-1, print list k
            print(k)           

        #For each element j in list k, check if each element in list k is 0
            for j in range (len(k)):        
                if k[j] != 0:             <---PROBLEM
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
print(is_prime(15))
```

The logic that I have is that when a number is divisible by 1 and itself, and not divisible by any other numbers from 2 to N-1, then it is a prime number. In the code above, I am having **trouble comparing the values of each element in list k**. I want to determine if the value of each element  k[j] == 0. If each element k[j] != 0 **and** N%1 == 0 **and** N%N == 0, then it is a prime number!

Any ideas to how I can solve this problem? Please refer to the link below to get a visualization of my code!
http://goo.gl/IVIRz7

Comment: If you add number divisible in a list why you dont try a condition on `len` list , why you check inside it?

Comment: @Arman I don't quite get what you mean. I'm checking inside the list because I want to know if the value of each element inside it is 0 or not.

Comment: Look at my answer , you should only check list length

Comment: @Arman TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. I tried adding int(N/2) but that doesn't make sense.

Comment: You can put `N` instead

Comment: if you want to get more speed have a look at [mine IsPrime implementation in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22477240/2521214)

Comment: if you want to get more speed have a look at [mine IsPrime implementation in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22477240/2521214)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to solve as follows:

```
def is_prime(n):
    i = 2
    while (i * i <= n):
        if (n % i == 0):
            return False
        i += 1
    return True
```

This code will work for `n >= 2` .

Comment: You can do even better by not checking any even values of `i` > 2.

Comment: Could you explain the logic behind using i*i . I think I know why you do it but just wanna hear your opinion. Thanks!

Comment: @misheekoh: If *ab* == N, then at least one of *a* & *b* must be <= sqrt(N); if *a* <= sqrt(N), then a\*a  <=  N.

Comment: If number `i` is a divisor of `n`, then `n/i`
 is also a divisor.
One of these two divisors is less than or equal to `√
n`. If that were not the case, `n` would be
a product of two numbers greater than `√
n`.

Comment: @scott-hunter if I introduce a check on even numbers,I would increase the time complexity of this code and affect the performance for a large data set, but your suggestion could be an optimization for a small one

Comment: @mabe02: If you make an explicit check for N being even, then initialize `i` to 3 and increment it by 2 each iteration, you (roughly) halve the number of iterations.

Answer (score 2):

```
import math

def is_prime(n):
    i = 3
    while (i <= math.sqrt(n)):
        if (n % i == 0):
            return False
        i += 2
    return True
```

This is best. Everyone above has mentioned its variation.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers will work, but I thought I'd explain your logical error.  Your reasoning in English is sound in that if any numbers between [2,N-1] divide N evenly, then you've found a non-prime number.

```
    for j in range (len(k)):        
        if k[j] != 0:             
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

What this loop checks is actually if the **first** number in k is 0 or not.  If it is nonzero, the number does not divide N evenly (note this does not mean that the other numbers do divide n evenly), so the number can still **possibly** be prime, but only if the remainder is nonzero for the remaining potential divisors.  In other words, you can return Falseas soon as you see a remainder of 0, but you can only return True only if **all** divisors have nonzero remainders.

Fixed:

```
        for j in range (len(k)):        
            if k[j] == 0:
                return False
            return True
```

The return True statement only executes if we manage to make it all the way through the loop without returning False.