# How do I return a false value for non-prime numbers in a method?

Tags: ruby, math, numbers

I have an exercise in which I have to create a method that returns true for prime numbers and false for non-prime numbers without the use of math operators.

```
def prime?(number)
  (2..number/2).none? {|n| return false if number <= 1 || number % n == 0}
end
```

Comment: What's your question? Is there a problem with the method you wrote? Outside of `prime?(1)` returning `true`, I think it does what you're wanting it to do.

Comment: Hello lurker thanks for you response. this code returns a true value for prime numbers, but it doesn't return a false value for non prime numbers

Comment: Yes it does. At least it does when I run it. For example, if I call `prime?(6)` it returns `false`.

Comment: `number >= 2 && (2..number/2).none? { |n| number % n == 0 }` is faster and makes more sense; but I can't find that your answer is in any way wrong. Also, smartass answer: `require 'prime'; def prime?(n); Prime.prime?(n); end` uses no math operators :P

Comment: I think something may be wrong with the test provided to me by the school

Comment: I just ran this code in irb and everything checks out. thanks lurker.

Comment: @EricHill in OP you stated `without the use of math operators` and you are using `/,||,<=,||,%,==` those all are math operators (arithmetic and logic). Without any use of them you need  to use assembler ... or you have specified which operators not to use? Also look here [Prime numbers by Eratosthenes quicker sequential than concurrently?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22477240/2521214) for some speedup ideas