# Python Prime number finder

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I have made a Prime number finder where you enter a number and it tells you weather it is a prime number.

```
while True:
    p = int(input('Enter a number '))
    for d in range(2, p):
        if p % d == 0:
            print(p, "is not a prime number!", d,"*", p//d,"=",p)
            break
        else:
            print(p, "is a prime number!")
            break
```

However it is displaying numbers that clearly aren't prime. I think it is only dividing it by 2 as all the odd numbers I have tried are being output as odd.

Can anyone help to fix this?

Comment: Think it through - when are you sure that a number is prime? Is it after you've checked whether it's divisible by two?

Comment: I think it is only dividing it by 2 as all the odd numbers I have tried are being output as odd?

Comment: for performance, you can take `for d in range(2, math.sqrt(p)+1):`

Comment: related: [What is the best algorithm for checking if a number is prime?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1801391/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check all the numbers before you can say it's prime. Currently, your loop exits at the first check (which is `d == 2`) and return `False` if `p % 2 == 0`, else `True`.

You should put the `else` statement at the end of the loop, like this:

```
while True:
    p = int(input('Enter a number '))
    for d in range(2, p):
        if p % d == 0:
            print(p, "is not a prime number!", d,"*", p//d,"=",p)
            break
    else:
        print(p, "is a prime number!")
```

The `else` is executed only if the loop did not end with `break`. This means that if not any divider was found, your number is prime.

Moreover, note that you do not have to check numbers until `p`, you can stop at `sqrt(p)` and iterate two by two: `for d in range(3, int(p**0.5) + 1, 2)`.

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly, i'm not quite sure why I put the break in to the code in the first place. :)

Comment: Also, you don't need to check as high as `p`.  Just do `for d in range(2, p ** 0.5 + 1):`

Comment: @User592 and also you should test 2, and then only the odd numbers ... no need to divide by `4,6,8,10,...`  for more speed/ideas see [Prime numbers by Eratosthenes quicker sequential than concurrently?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22477240/2521214)