# Optimizing the search for prime numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm, primes

I created a function for finding Prime Numbers, but the process takes a long time and uses a lot of memory. I need to optimize my code by making it more time and memory efficient.

The function is split into two parts:

The 1st part calculates odd numbers, the 2nd part is the `isSimple` method which searches for odd numbers that are prime.

I made some progress by moving the `Math.Sqrt(N)` outside of the for loop, but I'm not sure what to do next.

Any suggestions are welcome.

**Program:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //consider odd numbers
        for (int i = 10001; i <=90000; i+=2)
        {
            if (isSimple(i))
            {
                 Console.Write(i.ToString() + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
  //The method of finding primes
    private static bool isSimple(int N)
    {
        double koren = Math.Sqrt(N);

         // to verify a prime number or not enough to check whether it is //divisible number on numbers before its root
        for (int i = 2; i <= koren; i++)
        {   
            if (N % i == 0)
                 return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
You've merely dumped a homework problem on us.  We have no idea what *your* problem is.

Comment: This approach does not eat memory. If you want to trade speed for memory, consider Eratosthenes sieve

Comment: I need advice on how to change the code, for me, speed, and fun consumed memory

Comment: see [Prime numbers by Eratosthenes quicker sequential than concurrently?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22477240/2521214)

Comment: @Jack Your arguments are wrong

Comment: @Jack 
Where did you get that I did not optimize these functions?

Comment: @Jack 
Did not find it necessary. Do you need to know what I corrected before to find flaws in this code?

Comment: If you want help on optimizing your code, it would be good to see some methods you have tried so far. Make your question sound like a discussion, not a task.

Comment: @Jack 
Thanks, understood. Earlier introduced instead of dividing the root. And inserted it before the cycle

Answer (score 0):

You are checking all possible divisors with your `for (int i = 2; i <= koren; i++)`  That wastes time.  You can halve the time taken by checking only odd divisors.  You know that the given number `N` is odd, so no even number can be a divisor.  Try `for (int i = 3; i <= koren; i+=2)` instead.