# Largest Power: Find x and y with largest possible y for a given number n where x^y = n

Tags: java, math, exponentiation

I want to find the base and exponent for a given number such that exponent is the largest.For example: 16 can be expressed as 2^4, 4^2. The solution is 2^4 as 4 is the highest possible exponent.

So far, I have the following solution; I'd like to know if there are obvious flaws or performance problems with it:

```
public void getHighestPower(double a)
{
  double answer = 0;

  if(a%1 == 0) {

    for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(a); i++) {

      double res = Math.log(a) / Math.log(i);

      if (res > 0) {

        if (res % 1 == 0) {

          System.out.println(res);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *I want to find the base and exponent ...* Well, why not write an appropriate application then?

Comment: I actually have a solution but  was thinking if there is a better solution:

Comment: @PravinKumar I found a bug in mine approach (thx to  Rory Daulton) I updated my answer with corrected algorithm and code

Answer (score 2):

I got an impression that this is for integers. In that case **FPU** functions might be a problem for example `res` is `double` and you are testing if the fraction part is zero that will output wrong answers due to rounding errors of `log,/,%` operations. I would feel much safer with

```
if (fabs(res-floor(res)-0.5)>=0.5-1e-40)
```

instead of

```
if (res % 1 == 0)
```

but still the `log` and division operations in your `pow` will generate noise in fractional part of the result. So for bigger numbers you might get into trouble.

From performance point of view you might consider to decompose your number to its prime factors once and then use the minimal exponent used in the decomposition as the `y` if the number is decomposable. The `x` will be the multiplication of all the primes used once per every `y` exponent multiple. In case the exponents are not a multiple of `y` or the prime decomposition failed (`a!=1` at the end) result is original `a` so `a^1`. All this is computable on integers alone. Here simple example in **C++** doing this:

```cpp
void decompose(int &x,int &y,int a)
    {
    const int prime[]=
        {
           2,   3,   5,   7,  11,  13,  17,  19,  23,  29,  31,  37,  41,  43,  47,  53,  59,  61,  67,  71,
          73,  79,  83,  89,  97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173,
         179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281,
         283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409,
         419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541,
         547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659,
         661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809,
         811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941,
         947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997,1009,1013,1019,1021,1031,1033,1039,1049,1051,1061,1063,1069,
        1087,1091,1093,1097,1103,1109,1117,1123,1129,1151,1153,1163,1171,1181,1187,1193,1201,1213,1217,1223,
        1229,1231,1237,1249,1259,1277,1279,1283,1289,1291,1297,1301,1303,1307,1319,1321,1327,1361,1367,1373,
        1381,1399,1409,1423,1427,1429,1433,1439,1447,1451,1453,1459,1471,1481,1483,1487,1489,1493,1499,1511,
        1523,1531,1543,1549,1553,1559,1567,1571,1579,1583,1597,1601,1607,1609,1613,1619,1621,1627,1637,1657,
        1663,1667,1669,1693,1697,1699,1709,1721,1723,1733,1741,1747,1753,1759,1777,1783,1787,1789,1801,1811,
        1823,1831,1847,1861,1867,1871,1873,1877,1879,1889,1901,1907,1913,1931,1933,1949,1951,1973,1979,1987,
        1993,1997,1999,2003,2011,2017,2027,2029,2039,2053,2063,2069,2081,2083,2087,2089,2099,2111,2113,2129,
        2131,2137,2141,2143,2153,2161,2179,2203,2207,2213,2221,2237,2239,2243,2251,2267,2269,2273,2281,2287,
        2293,2297,2309,2311,2333,2339,2341,2347,2351,2357,2371,2377,2381,2383,2389,2393,2399,2411,2417,2423,
        2437,2441,2447,2459,2467,2473,2477,2503,2521,2531,2539,2543,2549,2551,2557,2579,2591,2593,2609,2617,
        2621,2633,2647,2657,2659,2663,2671,2677,2683,2687,2689,2693,2699,2707,2711,2713,2719,2729,2731,2741,
        2749,2753,2767,2777,2789,2791,2797,2801,2803,2819,2833,2837,2843,2851,2857,2861,2879,2887,2897,2903,
        2909,2917,2927,2939,2953,2957,2963,2969,2971,2999,3001,3011,3019,3023,3037,3041,3049,3061,3067,3079,
        3083,3089,3109,3119,3121,3137,3163,3167,3169,3181,3187,3191,3203,3209,3217,3221,3229,3251,3253,3257,
        3259,3271,3299,3301,3307,3313,3319,3323,3329,3331,3343,3347,3359,3361,3371,3373,3389,3391,3407,3413,
        3433,3449,3457,3461,3463,3467,3469,3491,3499,3511,3517,3527,3529,3533,3539,3541,3547,3557,3559,3571,
        3581,3583,3593,3607,3613,3617,3623,3631,3637,3643,3659,3671,3673,3677,3691,3697,3701,3709,3719,3727,
        3733,3739,3761,3767,3769,3779,3793,3797,3803,3821,3823,3833,3847,3851,3853,3863,3877,3881,3889,3907,
        3911,3917,3919,3923,3929,3931,3943,3947,3967,3989,4001,4003,4007,4013,4019,4021,4027,4049,4051,4057,
        4073,4079,4091,4093,4099,4111,4127,4129,4133,4139,4153,4157,4159,4177,4201,4211,4217,4219,4229,4231,
        4241,4243,4253,4259,4261,4271,4273,4283,4289,4297,4327,4337,4339,4349,4357,4363,4373,4391,4397,4409,
        4421,4423,4441,4447,4451,4457,4463,4481,4483,4493,4507,4513,4517,4519,4523,4547,4549,4561,4567,4583,
        4591,4597,4603,4621,4637,4639,4643,4649,4651,4657,4663,4673,4679,4691,4703,4721,4723,4729,4733,4751,
        4759,4783,4787,4789,4793,4799,4801,4813,4817,4831,4861,4871,4877,4889,4903,4909,4919,4931,4933,4937,
        4943,4951,4957,4967,4969,4973,4987,4993,4999,5003,5009,5011,5021,5023,5039,5051,5059,5077,5081,5087,
        5099,5101,5107,5113,5119,5147,5153,5167,5171,5179,5189,5197,5209,5227,5231,5233,5237,5261,5273,5279,
        5281,5297,5303,5309,5323,5333,5347,5351,5381,5387,5393,5399,5407,5413,5417,5419,5431,5437,5441,5443,
        5449,5471,5477,5479,5483,5501,5503,5507,5519,5521,5527,5531,5557,5563,5569,5573,5581,5591,5623,5639,
        5641,5647,5651,5653,5657,5659,5669,5683,5689,5693,5701,5711,5717,5737,5741,5743,5749,5779,5783,5791,
        5801,5807,5813,5821,5827,5839,5843,5849,5851,5857,5861,5867,5869,5879,5881,5897,5903,5923,5927,5939,
        5953,5981,5987,6007,6011,6029,6037,6043,6047,6053,6067,6073,6079,6089,6091,6101,6113,6121,6131,6133,
        6143,6151,6163,6173,6197,6199,6203,6211,6217,6221,6229,6247,6257,6263,6269,6271,6277,6287,6299,6301,
        6311,6317,6323,6329,6337,6343,6353,6359,6361,6367,6373,6379,6389,6397,6421,6427,6449,6451,6469,6473,
        6481,6491,6521,6529,6547,6551,6553,6563,6569,6571,6577,6581,6599,6607,6619,6637,6653,6659,6661,6673,
        6679,6689,6691,6701,6703,6709,6719,6733,6737,6761,6763,6779,6781,6791,6793,6803,6823,6827,6829,6833,
        6841,6857,6863,6869,6871,6883,6899,6907,6911,6917,6947,6949,6959,6961,6967,6971,6977,6983,6991,6997,
        7001,7013,7019,7027,7039,7043,7057,7069,7079,7103,7109,7121,7127,7129,7151,7159,7177,7187,7193,7207,
        7211,7213,7219,7229,7237,7243,7247,7253,7283,7297,7307,7309,7321,7331,7333,7349,7351,7369,7393,7411,
        7417,7433,7451,7457,7459,7477,7481,7487,7489,7499,7507,7517,7523,7529,7537,7541,7547,7549,7559,7561,
        7573,7577,7583,7589,7591,7603,7607,7621,7639,7643,7649,7669,7673,7681,7687,7691,7699,7703,7717,7723,
        7727,7741,7753,7757,7759,7789,7793,7817,7823,7829,7841,7853,7867,7873,7877,7879,7883,7901,7907,7919,
        };
    const int N=sizeof(prime)/sizeof(prime[0]);     // precomputed primes
    int i,j,a0=a;
    int f[N],fn=0;  // static list of { factor1,exponent1, factor2,exponent2, ... }
    // prime factors decomposition
    for (x=1,y=0,i=0;(prime[i]<=a)&&(i<N);i++)
        {
        for (j=0;(a%prime[i])==0;j++) a/=prime[i];  // decompose by factor prime[i]
        if (!j) continue;                           // ignore non factors
        f[fn]=prime[i]; fn++;                       // add factor to list
        f[fn]=j; fn++;                              // add exponent to list
        }
    if ((a!=1)||(fn==0)) { x=a0; y=1; return; }     // no decomposition
    // y = min exponent
    for (y=f[1],i=1;i<fn;i+=2)
     if (y>f[i]) y=f[i];
    // x = factors multiplicated (while multiple of y exponent is accounted for)
    for (x=1,i=0;i<fn;i+=2)
        {
        for (j=f[i+1];j>0;j-=y) x*=f[i+0];          // account each multiple of exponent
        if (j!=0) { x=a0; y=1; return; }            // stop if not a multiple
        }
    }
```

Note that I used static list of primes limiting the `a` value to keep this as simple as possible. You can use **SoE** to generate the primes on the run or even use non primes

```
{ 2,3,5,7,9,11,13... }
```

but the latter will result in slower complexity but still way faster than your approach. On the other hand it does not need an array. Look here:

- [Prime numbers by Eratosthenes quicker sequential than concurrently?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22477240/2521214)

for some inspiration on how to precompute the primes ...

Here result for all non trivial cases up to 1024:

```
    4 =     2^2
    8 =     2^3
    9 =     3^2
   16 =     2^4
   25 =     5^2
   27 =     3^3
   32 =     2^5
   36 =     6^2
   49 =     7^2
   64 =     2^6
   81 =     3^4
  100 =    10^2
  121 =    11^2
  125 =     5^3
  128 =     2^7
  144 =    12^2
  169 =    13^2
  196 =    14^2
  216 =     6^3
  225 =    15^2
  243 =     3^5
  256 =     2^8
  289 =    17^2
  324 =    18^2
  343 =     7^3
  361 =    19^2
  400 =    20^2
  441 =    21^2
  484 =    22^2
  512 =     2^9
  529 =    23^2
  576 =    24^2
  625 =     5^4
  676 =    26^2
  729 =     3^6
  784 =    28^2
  841 =    29^2
  900 =    30^2
  961 =    31^2
 1000 =    10^3
 1024 =    2^10
```

Comment: I do not run Java, but from your description it seems like your routine may return a wrong answer for `36=6^2`, since it equals `2^4*3^2` and the exponents are not equal. The exponents do, however, share a common factor greater than one.

Comment: Yes, I meant `144` which actually is `2^4*3^2`--how stupid of me. I hope I helped.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yes it helps I found and repaired the bug in the algo ... looks like it works correctly now.

Comment: @Spektre your code block has low readability and it makes it hard for reusing it in the future. can you make it more readable so it would make a better impact for other developers? here is something you can do: put your sample list in another code block, make your comments more aligned for better readability and add some blank lines between your code. thank you :)

Comment: @MohammadHosseinShojaeinia major blocks of code are separated by comment only lines, another empty line is redundant. Comments on the right after code are minor comments describing line/variable/const purpose. Dividing single function to code blocks would be harder to reuse as right now its copy and workable immediately. Dividing would break this. Changing formatting might be better readable for you but harder for others code styles are very subjective and you should not force yours on others unless you a dev team leader So sorry but I am un-wiling to make changes you proposed.