# Building prime number checker in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am new to C++ and coding, so excuse me if my knowledge is poor. I thought of a way to check if a number is prime (my code is below). My idea is that the user inputs a number, and uses a `for` loop with a variable `i` increasing in `+1` increments until it equals to the inputted number. Each time this increment happens, `i` is tested for being a factor of the inputted number. If it's a factor, the result of the modulus operator will be zero. In this case a variable `remainders` is incremented by `+1`, and, after all the values for `i` have been tested, if the value of `remainders` is 2, the tested number is prime, otherwise it is not  prime. My code is below, please inform me whether my idea is correct.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
int userNumber;
int remainders = 0;
cout << "Input the number to be tested:";
cin >> userNumber;

for (int i = 0; i == userNumber; i++){
        int remainderTest = userNumber % i;
    if (remainderTest = 0) {
        remainders ++;
    }
}

if (remainders == 2) {
    cout << "The number you inputted is prime!";
} else {
cout << "The number you entered is not prime!";
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (remainderTest = 0)` assigns 0 to `remainderTest` and then evaluates the condition, so it is always false. Besides the point really though since the loop `for (int i = 0; i == userNumber; i++)` will never be entered unless the user enters 0.

Comment: Easiest way to check if code works is to write some test cases and run the code.

Comment: You cannot take a modulo of 0.  Just start at 3, and increment by 2 every time.  2 is an exception.

Comment: Two problems with the for loop. Starting at 0 ensures a divide by 0 error, and the loop condition is only true if `i` and `userNumber` are the same, once again only possible with 0. Perhaps you meant `i < userNumber`?

Comment: Lot of algorithm to find prime numbers are **well known**... It should be easy to find one. Having said that, it is pointless to test even number (except 2) and no need to test above square root of a number. So if you want to test `623`, you should test `2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21 and 23` **at most**. In that case, you will find that it is not prime because `632 / 7 = 89`...

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22477240/2521214

Answer (score 2):

OP's code fails in various ways.

- `for (int i = 0; i == userNumber; i++){` only iterates the loop when `userNumber == 0` - and then only once.
- Code attempts `userNumber % 0` which is *undefined behavior* (UB).
- Code assigns rather than compares with `if (remainderTest = 0)`

Even if the loop iteration was fixed, OP's code is slow: O(n).

---

A short prime test algorithm to help OP along.

It iterates until `i` exceeds `n/i`.  (Tip: [avoid `i*i <= n`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70586358/building-prime-number-checker-in-c/70587100?noredirect=1#comment124792131_70587100))

```
bool prime_test(int n) {
  for (int i = 2; i <= n/i; i++) {
    if (n%i == 0) return false;
  }
  return n > 1; 
}
```

The one above is very short, yet still fast: O(sqrt(n)) and works for all `int n`: `[INT_MIN...INT_MAX]`.

Of course there are *many* potential optimizations, albeit with more code.

A favorite first optimization is to handle even numbers.

```
bool prime_testA(int n) {
  if (n % 2 == 0) {  // If even ...
    return n == 2;
  }
  for (int i = 3; i <= n/i; i += 2) { // Go up by 2
    if (n%i == 0) return false;
  }
  return n > 1; 
}
```

Comment: You can change the condition from `i <= n/i` to `i * i <= n` to save a division. Although the optimizer could combine it with the n%i calculation.

Comment: @Sebastian  "change the condition from i <= n/i to i * i <= n to save a division" --> A reasonable good compiler sees the nearby `n/i` and `n%i` and emits efficient code,  doing both for the price of one - if not, see `div()`.  Yet the suggestion to use `i * i <= n` leads to _undefined behavior_, possible an infinite loop, when `n` is a prime near `INT_MAX`.  With 32-bit `int`: `INT_MAX` is 2,147,483,647, a _prime_.  Obviously `i*i <= INT_MAX` is never false unless with UB.  Best to stick with `i <= n/i` to "works for all `int n`" than save a division and have code that fails corner cases.

Comment: Ok, you are right, this would need another test at the beginning for large n. Thank you for the advice. `avoid i*i <= n` is a bit strong IHMO to say generally. ;-)

Comment: @Sebastian Avoiding overflow is a good thing.  Learn how in small things to avoid such problems in [large things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_flight_V88#Launch_failure).

Comment: `i <= n/i` -> `i <= sqrt(n/i)`

Comment: @oleg.cherednik Perhaps you meant not `i <= sqrt(n/i)`, but `i <= sqrt(n)`? IAC, `sqrt(n)` has various corner cases that lead to trouble. `sqrt(some negative)` is a domain error. `sqrt(some integer type)` casts to `double`. On select machine, `int` is wider than 54 bits, or code is really using `long long`, etc., the conversion of an integer to `double` before the call may round down and form a square root slight smaller than needed limit. Weak compilers may not see constancy of the `sqrt(n)` & so call the somewhat expensive function repeatedly. Best to use integer math for an integer problem.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik What would make some sense is to call `if (n < 0) return false; int limit = isqrt(n); for (int i = 2; i <= limit; i++) { ...`.  That idea is really already covered under "there are many potential optimizations with more code.".  Above is just some _simply_, yet reliable code for all `int`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, I mean ‘i <= sqrt(n)’. Sorry for typo.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, i think that you should declare `i=2`, because it is useless to modulo 0 or 1.
Secondly, why you declare `i=0`, and after that `i==userNumber` :))
Beside, in line 12, it `==`, not `=`.
Your code (after fixed):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
int userNumber;
int remainders = 0;
cout << "Input the number to be tested:";
cin >> userNumber;

for (int i = 2; i <= userNumber; i++){
        int remainderTest = userNumber % i;
    if (remainderTest == 0) {
        remainders ++;
    }
}

if (remainders == 1) {
    cout << "The number you inputted is prime!";
} else {
cout << "The number you entered is not prime!";
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Notice that code fails when `userNumber == INT_MAX` and `INT_MAX` is a prime (e.g. 2,147,483,647) since `i <= userNumber` is always true.

Answer (score -1):

Your code has an in the for loop. Instead of `i == userNumber`, it should be `i < userNumber`. Here's an implementation of your idea as a function:

```
bool isPrime(int n) {
    bool isPrime = true;
    for (int i = 2; i<n; i++) {
        if (n%i == 0) isPrime = false;
    }
    return isPrime; 
}
```

You don't need to account for 1 and n being factors of any n if you don't include them in the for loop condition by starting at 2 and ending at n, so there is no need to keep track of remainders through a variable.

Comment: Did you test this? You want `n % i`, not `i % n` You can also break the loop once you've set `isPrime` to false or just return false there and true if the loop finishes.

Comment: `isPrime(Any int less than 2)` returns _true_, yet none of those are prime.