# How to Implement a Faster Algorithm for Searching for Primes in C

Tags: c, math, search, primes

First of all, I am fairly new to C, and know nothing about C++, and only took the [w3schools.org](https://www.w3schools.com/c/) tutorial on C, and made a few practice programs.  What I am looking for is something simple that can find all primes form 1 to 1000000 in under half an hour.  I do not know how to implement anything complex like [Sieve of Atkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin?scrlybrkr=07810e97) or other complex algorithms.  Can you either explain Sieve of Atkin either simpler (like in laymen's terms) or demonstrate it in C? Please keep in mind that I just took the beginner course in C from w3schools.

The code that I am using is as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int n = 0, i, b, e, flag = 0;

int main() {
    printf("Enter a positive integer that will be the higher bound: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    for (n = 0; n < b; n++) {
        if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
        flag = 1;
        }
      for (i = 2; i <= n / 2; ++i) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
          flag = 1;
        }
      }
      if (flag == 0) {
        printf("%d is a prime number.\n", n);
        } else {
        }
        flag = 0;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"1 to 1000000 in under half an hour"_: half an hour for this is incredibly slow. I think even the dumbest algorithm should be faster than that on an average desktop PC.

Comment: BTW: google "sieve of eratosthenes". This is quite efficient and really simple.

Comment: The baseline test that I used is on the basic plan on the online IDE replit.com.  I forget the exact specs, but they are not good.  I will run it on my home computer and update it accordingly.
EDIT: It works by dividing n by every number less then n, if all of them are not devisable, then it is a prime.

Comment: Even the dumbest algorithm would be able to find the first 1000000 prime numbers on a platform with very little performance in a couple of seconds.

Comment: `for (int i = 2; i <= 1000000; i++) { int f = count_factors(i); if (f == 2) printf("%d is prime.\n", i); }`.  Writing the function `count_factors()` is left as an exercise :)

Comment: So what's the problem on repl.it? Maybe you should [edit] and show your code instead of just describing it.

Comment: Approximately the crudest function (which mistreats both 0 and 1 as prime numbers) — `static int IsPrime(unsigned number) { for (unsigned i = 2; i < number; i++) { if (number % i == 0) return 0; } return 1; }` — takes  under under 2 minutes for the numbers  up to one million running on a MacBook Pro using macOS Big SUr 11.6.4  — 2.6 GHz 6-core Intel Core i7.  I got times of 1m 16s and 1m 15s.

Comment: see [Prime numbers by Eratosthenes quicker sequential than concurrently?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22477240/2521214) for full set of ideas ... `primes form 1 to 1000000 in under half an hour` ??? more like below 40ms with SoE on 10+ year old PC... on what are you computing old 8bit Z80 with 3.5MHz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's code limits factor testing with `for (i = 2; i <= n / 2; ++i) {` - a modest first step.

Yet past the square root of `n` , there are no factors. Since the root is smaller (usually) , than `n/2`, this is *much* quicker.

We could use `test_factor * test_factor <= n`, but `test_factor * test_factor` may overflow.  Use `test_factor <= n/test_factor`.  Smart compilers will see the nearby `n/test_factor` and `n%test_factor` and emit code that executes about as fast as just one of those.

Code could calculate `int limit = sqrt(n)`, but that 1) has edge case problems as `sqrt()` may no return *exactly* the sought after root even when it is a whole number 2) may lose needed precession when the integer type has more precision that `double`. 3) Incurs a floating point cost vs. the nearly no additional cost of `test_factor <= n/test_factor`.

OP's code sets a flag when a factor is found and then continues to look for more.  Yet there is no reason to continue looking.  This speeds things up a lot to quit the loop once a factor is found.

We could also check every other value as numbers divided by 2 are not prime - with one exception: 2.  This is a *modest* improvement.

```
bool is_prime(int n) {
  if (n % 2 == 0) {
    return n == 2;
  }
  for (int test_factor = 3; test_factor <= n / test_factor; test_factor += 2) {
    if (n % test_factor == 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return n > 1;  // No factors and n is more than 1.
}
```

Use

```
for (n = 2; n < b; n++) {
  if (is_prime(n)) {
    printf("%d is a prime number.\n", n);
  }
}
```

Note: less than 2 seconds to print all the primes less than 1000000.

---

For a sieve approach. See [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Pseudocode) pseudo code.