# Schonhage-Strassen Multiplication implementation error

Tags: python, algorithm, multiplication, bigint, number-theory

I am attempting to implement the Schonhage-Strassen multiplication algorithm using NTT, and am running into a problem where the final resulting vector is not actually equal to what it should be.

For two input vectors `a`, and `b`, each consisting of `N` "digits" of `K` bits (the final `N/2` entries of each set to 0), each, given a modulus `M = 2^(2*K)+1`, a root of unity `w = N^(4*K-1) | w^N = 1 mod M`, a modular inverse of this value `wi | wi*w = 1 mod M`, and `u | u*N = 1 mod M`, the following python code is used to (attempt to) multiply these vectors using the Schonhage-Strassen algorithm:

```
#a and b are lists of length N, representing large integers
A = [ sum([ (a[i]*pow(w,i*j,M))%M for i in range(N)]) for j in range(N)] #NTT of a
B = [ sum([ (b[i]*pow(w,i*j,M))%M for i in range(N)]) for j in range(N)] #NTT of b
C = [ (A[i]*B[i])%M for i in range(N)] #A * B multiplied pointwise
c = [ sum([ (C[i]*pow(wi,i*j,M))%M for i in range(N)]) for j in range(N)] #intermediate step in INTT of C
ci = [ (i*u)%M for i in c] #INTT of C, should be product of a and b
```

In theory, taking the NTT of `a` and `b`, multiplying pointwise, then taking the INTT of the result should give the product, if I am not mistaken, and I have tested these methods for NTT and INTT to confirm that they are inverses of each other. However, the final resulting vector `ci`, rather than being equal to the product of `a` and `b`, is the product where each element is taken modulo `M`, giving an incorrect result for the product.

For example, running a test with `N=K=8`, and random vectors for `a, b`, gives the following:

```
M = 2^(2*8)+1 = 65537
w = 16, wi = 61441
u = 57345
a = [212, 251, 84, 186, 0, 0, 0, 0] (3126131668 as an integer)
b = [180, 27, 234, 225, 0, 0, 0, 0] (3790216116)
NTT(a) = [733, 66681, 147842, 92262, 130933, 107825, 114562, 127302]
NTT(b) = [666, 64598, 80332, 54468, 131236, 186644, 181708, 88232]
Pointwise product of above two lines mod M = [29419, 39913, 25015, 14993, 42695, 49488, 52438, 51319]
INTT of above line (i.e. result) = [38160, 50904, 5968, 11108, 15616, 62424, 41850, 0] (11848430946168040720)
Actual product of a x b = [38160, 50904, 71505, 142182, 81153, 62424, 41850, 0] (11848714628791561488)
```

In this example, and in pretty much every time I try it, the elements of the actual product and the result of my algorithm are the same for several elements near the beginning and end of the vector, but towards the middle they deviate. As I mentioned above, the elements of `ci` are each equal to the elements of `a*b` modulo `M`. I must be misunderstanding something about this algorithm, though I'm not entirely sure what. Am I using the wrong modulus somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Beware number theory and **NTT** are not my field of expertise so read with prejudice but I did successfully implement **NTT** in **C++** on my own and used it for bignum multiplications (`bigint`, `bigfloatingpoint`, `bigfixedpoint`) so Here some insigtst of mine. I strongly suggest you read both 2 of mine related QAs first:

- [Translation from Complex-FFT to Finite-Field-FFT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18547575/2521214) code that finds and verifies the NTT prime root of unity and related parameters
- [Modular arithmetics and NTT (finite field DFT) optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18577076/2521214) mine optimized 32 bit NTT

so you can compare your results/code/constants with mine. However I evolved my NTT to use single hardcoded prime (biggest rooth of unity that fits in 32bit value).

Now what can be wrong with your code.  I do not code in python but I do not see **NTT** code in your question. Anyway from what I can see:

1. **check your root or unity**

   In your question you mention condition:

   ```
   w^N = 1 mod M
   ```

   but that is far from enough. See the first link above it describes all conditions that must be met (with code that finds and check it). I am not sure your parameters complies all needed conditions and you just forget or miss wrote those or not **so check it**. IIRC I struggled with those conditions too as at the time I coded this there where very little NTT info at my disposal and most of them where incomplete or wrong...
2. **You are not using modular arithmetics !!!**

   I assume Your prime is `M` (in mine terminology its `p`) so all the subresults must be smaller than `M` which is clearly not true in your example:

   ```
   M = 65537
   NTT(a) = [733, 66681, 147842, 92262, 130933, 107825, 114562, 127302]
   NTT(b) = [666, 64598, 80332, 54468, 131236, 186644, 181708, 88232]
   ```

   as you can see only first element of both NTTs are valid all others are bigger than `M` that is wrong !!!
3. **beware of overflows**

   Your `M` is **really small** `~16bit` in comparison to your input values which look `~8bit` that can overflow really fast invalidating your **NTT** results too.

   Here a quote from my second link I found out the hard and empirical way:

   > To avoid overflows for big datasets, limit input numbers to p/4 bits.
   >   Where p is number of bits per NTT element so for this 32 bit version
   >   use max (32 bit/4 -> 8 bit) input values.

   so in your case you should process `16/4 = 4bit` chunks instead of 8 bit or use much bigger `M` for example like mine `0xC0000001` which is `~32bit`.

   This explains your observationa that first elements of product are good and then not ... realize if you multiply 2 8bit numbers you got 16 bit ... now realize you are doing more recursive additions of the multiplicated subresults so it will get above 16 bit `M` very soon in your case right in the second value ...

So in summary **you are not using modular arithemics**, have **too small prime** and/or process **too big chunks of data** and **possibly** have also **wrong prime selected**.